# PAM File Modification for Google Authenticator

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

i use the google authenticator for the ssh authentication, but i use a publickey + authenticator or a password + authenticator (when no publickey is defined it should be ask only for password, but i don't know how i can setup this.)

My sshd_config file (edits):

```
UsePAM Yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive password,keyboard-interactive
```

and my PAM file:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required pam_sepermit.so
#auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
#-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare 
#auth [success=done new_authtok_reqd=done default=die]       required     
pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
auth        sufficient   pam_google_authenticator.so
auth        required     pam_unix.so no_warn try_fist_pass
```

It is working perfectly in normal login, but i use netbeans in development and in ssh mode - it is able to login successfully with ssh without a correct password or certificate in mode: keyboard-interactive (also the authentificator code)

Log:

```
Connection established
Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
aes256-ctr is not available.
aes192-ctr is not available.
aes256-cbc is not available.
aes192-cbc is not available.
CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
kex: server: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
kex: server: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
kex: server: none,zlib@openssh.com
kex: server:
kex: server:
kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
kex: client: none
kex: client: none
kex: client:
kex: client:
kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT sent
expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
Host '' is known and matches the RSA host key
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
Next authentication method: publickey
Authentications that can continue: password
Next authentication method: password
Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
Next authentication method: publickey
Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
```

Comment: Can nobody help me?